# Show ImageButton Template only for userid else hide

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

After login I create a `Session[ID]` and create a `GridView` with a `TemplateField` column.
I tried to make visible only the `ImageButton` of user id.

I am trying to do something like:

```
if (Session["SessionID"]=ID_user) //ID_User is a column of a table
    ImageButton.Visible=true;
else
    ImageButton.Visible=false;
```

Comment: Please don't add " (C#)" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GridViewRowDataBound` event:

inside it, get the `UserID` from the row and match it to the `SessionID`. If there's a match, use `FindControl` to get the corresponding `ImageButton` for that row and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this mode (hiding cells that didnt match with sessionID)

protected void GridViewRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
          {

```
         if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == Session["Codice_ID"].ToString())
         {

             e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = true;


         }
         else 
         {
             e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
         }




 }
```